# Derivative of $\; y={(1+e^x)}^{0.5}\; $ using the definition of the derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$y={(1+e^x)}^{0.5} =f(x)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \lim_{h\to0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

My attempt I got down to 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+e^xe^h)^{0.5}-(1+e^x)^{0.5}}{h}$$

I can't see where to go from here

Comment: This is not a differential equation. Do you mean you want to find the derivative of $(1+e^x)^{0.5}$?

Comment: Yeah sorry that's what I meant

Comment: I see, I've submitted an answer. Do you need to do it with the definition of the derivative?

Comment: Yes I have to do it with the definition

Comment: You can use definition of derivative to prove intermediate results you will be needing. Then differentiate like you do. :P

Comment: You missed a sqrt

Comment: What do you mean by that sorry I don't get it

Answer (score 2):

Provided you know

$$\lim_{h\to0}{e^h-1\over h}=1$$

you can take what you got to and write

$$\begin{align}
{(1+e^xe^h)^{0.5}-(1+e^x)^{0.5}\over h}&={(1+e^xe^h)^{0.5}-(1+e^x)^{0.5}\over h}\cdot{(1+e^xe^h)^{0.5}+(1+e^x)^{0.5}\over(1+e^xe^h)^{0.5}+(1+e^x)^{0.5}}\\
&={(1+e^xe^h)-(1+e^x)\over h\left((1+e^xe^h)^{0.5}+(1+e^x)^{0.5}\right)}\\
&={e^x\over(1+e^xe^h)^{0.5}+(1+e^x)^{0.5}}\cdot{e^h-1\over h}
\end{align}$$

When you take the limit now, you get $e^x/2(1+e^x)^{0.5}$.

The multiplication step is a standard trick for working with a square root.  Computing the limit of $(e^h-1)/h$ requires more than the definition of the derivative; it requires some definition of the exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h & = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}-\sqrt{1+e^x}}h \\ 
& = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}-\sqrt{1+e^x}}h\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}}{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}}\\ 
& = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{1+e^{x+h}-1-e^{x}}{h}{\cdot}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}} \\
& = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{e^x(e^h-1)}{h}{\cdot}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}} \\
&= e^x\cdot\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{e^h-1}{h}{\cdot}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}}\\
&= \frac{e^x}{2\sqrt{1+e^{x}}}
\end{align*}$$
For the last part you just have to recognize that you get the derivative of $e^x$ by multiplying by $e^x$: $$e^x\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h\overset{}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^{x+h}-e^h}{h}=e^x$$ and so this means that $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1$. The other result is very obvious: $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{x}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1+e^{x}}}.$$

Comment: One can not really apply l'Hopital to this limit, since this would invoke the derivative of exp that is defined as exactly this limit. So this reasoning is circular. Just say that this is the difference quotient of exp(h) that has the derivative exp(0) as limit.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is: $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
Now, when finding the derivative of $(1+e^x)^{0.5}$, we also need to multiply with the inner derivative, which is $e^x$. Thus we get

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{(1+e^x)^{0.5}} \cdot e^x$$

Comment if you want some clarification.

Comment: I know how to find the derivative that's simple it's using the limits to the stage I got that I don't know what to do from there

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}-\sqrt{1+e^x}=\frac{1+e^{x+h}-(1+e^x)}{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}}$$

$$\implies \frac{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}-\sqrt{1+e^x}}h=e^x\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x}}\cdot\frac{e^h-1}h$$

$$\implies \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}-\sqrt{1+e^x}}h=e^x\cdot\frac1{\lim_{h\to0}(\sqrt{1+e^{x+h}}+\sqrt{1+e^x})}\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h$$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: @Bob, How about this?

Answer (score -1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}&=\frac{\sqrt{1+e^x}-\sqrt{1+e^{x_0}}}{x-x_0}=\frac{1+e^x-1-e^{x_0}}{x-x_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^x}+\sqrt{1+e^{x_0}}}\\
&= \frac{e^x-e^{x_0}}{x-x_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^x}+\sqrt{1+e^{x_0}}} \xrightarrow{x \to x_0}e^{x_0}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+e^{x_0}}}
\end{align}
$$